# Выровнять контент страницы на 100% экрана по высоте. Старый метод

Tags: css

Доброго всем времени суток.

```
    [link text][1]
```

Реальзовано растягивание на всю страницу по высоте. Минус метода - страница все же прокручивается, но до самого низа. Можно ли как-то этого избежать?

P.S. Знаю, что можно подобное реализовать на: Position absolute, height calc, table. Ищу альтернативу, описанную выше.

Comment: В коде мало что понятно. Используйте jsfiddle.net и перефразируйте вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
html {
position:relative; 
min-height:100%;
}
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
}
```